# Ruby and Erlang, talking

Tags: ruby, erlang, ipc

I want to let a Ruby app spawn an Erlang process and let it report back to Ruby. Until now I looked into [Erlectricity](https://github.com/mojombo/erlectricity), but couldn't figure out a way to achieve this without letting Erlang spawn Ruby again, which would be a bit messy I guess.

What other ways are there? *MQ? Sockets? What do you think fits best with a single app, talking to a single Erlang process? It really doesn't have to scale (yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Ruby `Open4.popen4` to spawn `escript` process which reads from `stdin` and writes to `stdout` with  simple serialization (another option is to use escript params to pass data to Erlang). Escript in turn has full native access to distributed Erlang nodes. Not a rocket science, but it works and much easier to implement than sockets.

Comment: Seems to be the most result-oriented solution so far. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using [Ernie](https://github.com/mojombo/ernie). It's an RPC mechanism that makes it pretty easy to talk between Ruby and Erlang (and other languages if you install additional modules).

Answer (score 0):

[Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) supports both Erlang and Ruby:

> Thrift is a software framework for
>   scalable cross-language services
>   development. It combines a software
>   stack with a code generation engine to
>   build services that work efficiently
>   and seamlessly between C++, Java,
>   Python, PHP, Ruby, Erlang, Perl,
>   Haskell, C#, Cocoa, JavaScript,
>   Node.js, Smalltalk, and OCaml.

Also, this question might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436418/ruby-in-erlang) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028172/call-erlang-from-ruby).